# Need help estimating standard error in R using bootstrap

Tags: r, confidence-interval

This is an example problem for my exam that I don't understand.
The observed waiting times to failure of air-conditioning equipment are 3, 5, 7, 18, 43, 85, 91, 98, 100, 130, 230, and 487. Suppose you want to estimate the standard error of the median waiting time to fail. Give a precise description how you would estimate that standard error using the nonparametric bootstrap.

My code in R gives an error:

```
x <- c(3,5,7,18,43,85,91,98,100,130,230,487)
median(x)

B <- 999
bs.median <- rep(B)
for (b in B) bs.median[b] <- median(sample(x,12,replace=TRUE))
sd(bs.median)
```

Can somebody tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a few minor things in your code, I believe this will work.
I believe I have the same sample questions, perhaps you will benefit from my other answers as well.

```
1

x <- c(3,5,7,18,43,85,91,98,100,130,230,487)
median(x)

B <- 999
bs.median <- rep(NA,B)
for (b in 1:B) bs.median[b] <- median(sample(x,12,replace=TRUE))
sd(bs.median)
```

The other answers to the sample questions:

2:  103 students registered for this course, a fraction  of which is female. Attendees
are a random sample out of these 103 students. Suppose 73 students attend a class, and 18
are female. Give the algorithm to estimate  by the secant method.

```
g.prime <- function(p,n,x){
  x/p -(n-x)/(1-p)
}

p0 <- 0.1
p1 <- 0.4

max.steps <- 20
p <- c(p0,p1,rep(NA,max.steps-2))
for (i in 3:max.steps){
  p.t <- p[i-1]
  g.prime.t <- g.prime(p.t,73,18)
  p.t.min.1 <- p[i-2]
  g.prime.t.min.1 <- g.prime(p.t.min.1,73,18)
  p[i] <- p.t - g.prime.t*(p.t-p.t.min.1)/(g.prime.t-g.prime.t.min.1)
}
p
```

3b Write R-code that calculates the loglikelihoodfunction as required by optim. Your code does not have to be syntactically correct, but it should be clear to anyone with access to R how to program the loglikelihoodfunction.

```
loglik <- function(p,y,d){
  a <- p[1:2]
  b <- p[3:4]
  denominator <- 1+exp(-a[1]-a[2]*d)+exp(-b[1]-b[2]*d)
  bicycle <- exp(-a[1]-a[2]*d)
  public <- exp(-b[1]-b[2]*d)
  p <- ifelse(y==1, 1/denominator, bicycle/denominator)
  p <- ifelse(y==3, public/denominator, p)
  -sum(log(p))
}
```

3c Give appropriate starting values and the relevant call to optim to have R Önd the ML estimator.

```
df$y <- ifelse(df$choice=='car',1,3)
df$y <- ifelse(df$choice=='bicycle',2,df$y)
table(df$y)
p0 <- c(0,0,0,0)
optim(p0,loglik,y=df$y,d=df$distance)
```

I hope you find these answers useful!

4. Consider the R-code given below. This is part of a parametric bootstrap study
   to study estimation of the mean of the (; )-distribution. Do the Önal answers surprise
   you? Explain

No. The variable b has two roles in the program. It acts as a counter in the bootstrap
iterations (for (b in 1:B)), and its value is also used to generate the parametric bootstrap
sample (rgamma(n, shape=a,rate=b)). In each iteration, the sample is drawn from a
distribution with di§erent parameter